# Зачем нужна функция std::iter_swap?

Tags: c++

В стандартной библиотеке есть функция [`std::iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap).

Зачем она нужна, если можно самому написать

```
using std::swap; swap(*a, *b);
```

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, эта функция выполняет такую же роль, как и `std::next`, она гарантирует, что операция разыменования итератора производится для *lvalue*, а не rvalue.

Стандарт требует что для переменной-итератора `i` можно написать `*i`, однако он не требует что можно написать `*f()`, поэтому следующий код может не скомпилироваться (или работать не так), если итератор не поддерживает разыменование *rvalue*:

```
swap(*first, *std::max_element(std::next(first), last));  // ПЛОХО, может не работать
```

Во-вторых, для того чтобы была возможность использовать пользовательские реализации функции `swap`, вместо `std::swap(*a, *b)` надо писать

```
using std::swap; swap(*a, *b);
```

что выглядит несколько длинно, и об этом легко забыть.

Также, теоретически `std::iter_swap` может быть перегружена для итераторов связанных списков, так что вместо обмена самих элементов списка, меняются только связи на его элементы. Впрочем алгоритмы стандартной библиотеки вызывают `std::iter_swap`, что отключает поиск пользовательских функций.

Comment: Не очень понял, причем тут `итератор не поддерживает разыменование rvalue`. `std::swap` принимает `T&`, которые к rvalue никак не могут привязаться в принципе. Не важно что там, итератор или нет. P.S. В коде закрывающая скобка отсутствует.

Comment: Где написано про lvalue? Я вижу `All input iterators i support the expression *i`.

Comment: будьте добры конкретнее. Призывы читать всё подряд больше похожи на отмашку, чем на достойный ответ.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, `std::iter_swap` может вызывать `std::swap`, то, что он этого не делает скорее заслуга компиляторов(библиотек), а не их обязанность. Ну а вообще все плюсы, в целом, высосаны из пальца. Я ни в коем случае не говорю, что ответ плох, просто функция действительно бесполезна, по сути.